# Avoid creating duplicate method which only needs a different operator

Tags: c#, operators

I have some method that returns the closest `Foo` *behind* a given position.

```
public Foo ClosestFooBehindPosition(float pos)
{
    Foo closestFoo = null;

    foreach (Foo foo in FooManager.Foos)
    {
        if (foo.Pos < pos)
        {
            if (closestFoo = null) closestFoo = foo;
            else
            {
                bool thisFooIsCloser = closestFoo.pos > foo.Pos;
                if (thisFooIsCloser) closestFoo = foo;
            }
        }
    }
    return closestFoo;
}
```

I also require one which returns the closest `Foo` *Ahead* of the given position.

Is there a way of doing this that doesn't require duplicating most of the method, since the only difference would be to swap the `<` and `>` around?

Answer (score 1):

You could pass a lambda/function argument which evaluate it.

For example:

```
// use the Func<,,> for this.
public Foo ClosestFooPosition(Func<float, float, bool> evaluator, float pos)
{
    Foo closestFoo = null;

    foreach (Foo foo in FooManager.Foos)
    {
        // just call it here to evualuate it.
        if (evaluator(foo.Pos, pos))
        {
            if (closestFoo = null) closestFoo = foo;
            else
            {
                // don't forget here also. 
                bool thisFooIsCloser = !evaluator(foo.Pos, closestFoo.pos);                                            
                if (thisFooIsCloser) closestFoo = foo;
            }
        }
    }
    return closestFoo;
}
```

---

Call it like:

```
// define a function for it...
private bool GreaterThan(float first, float second)
{
    return first > second;
}

// pass the function without the parentesis
var fooBehind = ClosestFooPosition(GreaterThan, pos);
```

---

Or even shorter:

```
// inline the function as lambda
var fooBehind = ClosestFooPosition((first, second) => first > second, pos);

var fooAhead = ClosestFooPosition((first, second) => first < second, pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `Foo` implements [`IComparable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=net-5.0), you could use [`System.Linq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0)'s [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) and [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-5.0)/[`Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-5.0) methods.

```
class Foo: IComparable<Foo>
{
    int IComparable<Foo>.CompareTo(Foo other)
    {
        if (other.Pos > this.Pos) return -1;
        if (other.Pos == this.Pos) return 0;
        if (other.Pos < this.Pos) return 1;
    }
}
```

```
// Find the largest value of `Pos` that's less than `pos`.
public Foo ClosestFooBehindPosition(float pos) =>
    FooManager?.Foos?.Where(foo => foo.Pos < pos).Max();

// Find the smallest value of `Pos` that's larger than `pos`.
public Foo ClosestFooAfterPosition(float pos) =>
    FooManager?.Foos?.Where(foo => foo.Pos > pos).Min();
```

Because of the use of the [null-conditional (`?.`) operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-), if `FooManager`, `FooManager.Foos`, or the result of `Max`/`Min` are `null`, then you will still get `null` back from your method(s).

---

If you can't change `Foo` or you might want to reserve `IComparable<Foo>` for another use, you could [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0) the `Foo.Pos` property and take the [`First`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-5.0)/[`Last`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=net-5.0) to achieve the same result.

```
public Foo ClosestFooBehindPosition(float pos) =>
    FooManager?.Foos?.Where(foo => foo.Pos < pos)
                     .OrderBy(foo => foo.Pos)
                     ?.Last();

public Foo ClosestFooAfterPosition(float pos) =>
    FooManager?.Foos?.Where(foo => foo.Pos > pos)
                     .OrderBy(foo => foo.Pos)
                     ?.First();
```